# Updating a dylib to reference correct versions of other dylibs (Homebrew)

Tags: opencv, homebrew, dylib

I'm trying to build a program that uses QT and OpenCV.  It compiles correctly, but when I run the application I get:

```
Starting /Users/Me/MyApp/Contents/MacOS/Foo...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libavformat.54.29.104.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/Users/Me/MyApp/Contents/MacOS/Foo exited with code 0
```

I've had a look in my `/usr/local/lib`, the files are properly linked there, the issue is that `libav` is now at a higher version and `opencv` doesn't reflect this (e.g. looking at the opencv dylib in a hex editor I see that it wants what it says above, but what's actually in my lib folder is e.g. version `54.59.106`.  I've tried runnning `brew update/upgrade` and relinking everything, but no luck.

I can make a quick fix by copying the offending dylibs and renaming them to older versions.  This does cause the program to open correctly, but it's a bit of a hack.

Obviously I could probably fix this with a reinstall of the relevant libraries, but that takes precious time.. from this thread it seems like the only option, but I don't know if that's been fixed yet: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only way to fix this was to run:

`brew rm ffmpeg && brew install ffmpeg`

`brew rm opencv && brew install opencv`

Probably didn't need to repour ffmpeg, but I didn't see any harm in it.  Turns out this happens sometimes when a package updates to a major new version and the other package hasn't also been updated yet.

Comment: But you forced update the OpenCV which might not be what the user wants. For instance, I cannot upgrade from 4.5 to 4.7 because it breaks logic to detect charuco corners and requires major code refactor. How can we have homebrew refer to older versions of other dylibs is the question?

Comment: There may be a better solution now, as this question/answer is now over a decade old. I suspect for many people the answer is to just not homebrew and compile OpenCV from scratch - it's pretty fast nowadays and you can fine-tune what gets built in. In my experience it's easier to distribute libraries with the application package and not rely on whatever homebrew might have installed.